# Specific Users Lack Datadog And Intercom Logs

Tags: logging, datadog, intercom

For our React-Native application, we use Datadog to log errors and Intercom to handle customer support.

Unfortunately, for certain, specific users, we entirely & consistently lack logs across both platforms.

Are you aware of VPNs or other service providers blocking such logging tools?

Comment: There are many things that could block Intercom and Datadog's browser-sdk, including ad blockers, DNS blackholes, VPNs, network rules, and so on. You'd have to work directly with the affected users to determine the cause.